# Create Event in AEM 6.4

Tags: java, aem

How can I create an programatically Event for UnitTests in AEM 6.4 after `EventPropertiesMap` has been removed?

```
List<EventPropertiesMap> fakeModifications = new ArrayList<>();
fakeModifications.add(PageModification.deleted(pagePath, 
StringUtils.EMPTY).getEventProperties());

Map eventProps = new HashMap();
eventProps.put("modifications", fakeModifications);

return new Event("com/day/cq/wcm/core/page", eventProps);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution hoping to share the pain of an upgrade with others :-)
If you got a better solution I'm more than welcome!

```
List<Map<String, ?>> fakesList = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
Map<String, ?> fakeModifications = PageModification.deleted(pagePath, StringUtils.EMPTY).getEventProperties();
fakesList.add(fakeModifications);

Map<String, List<Map<String, ?>>> eventProps = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, ?>>>();
eventProps.put("modifications", fakesList);
return new Event("com/day/cq/wcm/core/page", eventProps);
```